# JTable listener to open JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog

Sorry if there is a similar question, couldn't find anything.

Basically, in my program, I have items in a JTable with their qualities, description, price etc. on each row. I want to open a new JDialog with more info about the item whenever it is selected from the table. However, **I don't know how to get the selected row** and for example change its colour to know that it is selected. The following I tried and it doesn't do anything. I guess the source of the event has nothing to do with the model.

```
public void addListener(){

    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == table.getSelectionModel()) {
                ItemDialog id = new ItemDialog(table.getSelectedRow());
            }

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). Hard code some data for the table.

Comment: `JTable#getSelectedRow` will tell you the row which is selected (or -1 if there are none), but what you probably want is the data which represents your row, which will be depended on the type of `TableModel` you are using.  And, if I was your user, I wouldn't be happy with your popping up a dialog each time I change selection.  Consider using a `JButton` (more info) or `JPopupMenu` instead...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected row by adding a list selection listener to the selection model of the table:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * Adapted version of a standard Java demo project:
 * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?
 *     code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples
 *     /components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components
 *     /SimpleTableDemo.java
 */
public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
                "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", 5, false},
                {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true},
                {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", 2, false},
                {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", 20, true},
                {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", 10, false}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            selectionEvent -> {
                if (!selectionEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()
                    && selectionEvent.getSource().equals(table.getSelectionModel()))
                    System.out.println("Row index: " + table.getSelectedRow());
            }
        );
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SimpleTableDemo::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just beware that ListSelectionListener notifies you of both when a value is unselected and selected

Comment: Yes, you're right: use the `getValueIsAdjusting` method (only if it returns `false`) if you only want to handle the final event. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few lines of code from one of my old projects. (I'm intentionally not providing full code as a lot of it would be irreverent)

**Add MouseListener to the table**

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { // change it to whatever key or click you want
                    if (table.getRowCount() != 0) {
                        printSelectedRowData();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**Here is the printSelectedRowData() method**

```
public void printSelectedRowData() {
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                Object[] rowData = new Object[table.getColumnCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    rowData[i] = table
                            .getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), i);
                    System.out.println(table.getColumnName(i) + ":  "
                            + rowData[i] + "\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error  ");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: A ListSelectionListener is a better idea, as MouseListener doesn't take into account keyboard selection (might be a good thing, might be a bad thing), but you should NEVER access UI elements fro. Outside the Event Dispatching Thread, you could get yourself into a thread race condition which could produce erroneous results

Comment: Sure you're all right, as i mentioned it was an old project. Its just another way of doing the same thing may be less secure.